# Cordova FileTransferError - code

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to make a download of some files. And i catch a FileTransferError with code: 3. Where can i find a table to understand the code number what means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransferError) or read the source. You'll see that 3 is a FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR.

Comment: Ah ok. I see that there are the 3 constants, but no understand how link.

Comment: @Simon MacDonald i am also facing this issue what is that connection_error means can you give some explaination

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had this issue when my web server had an invalid SSL certificate (the domain didn't match). It worked fine over HTTP or HTTPS with a valid certificate. Android and iOS you can use "trustAllHosts" during development (but, as the documentation says, you'd be highly recommended not to use that setting in production).

Comment: i am not understanding the ssl certificate part what is it to do with connection_error

Comment: The OS may require resources to be delivered over HTTP (e.g. app transport policy), hence the file transfer failing.